# Python Log message into tokens

Tags: python

I have a log message in the format

```
[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (ThreadID) <Module name> [Logging level]    Message Desciption : This is the message.
```

I want to create dictionary in the form

```
{'time stamp': 2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053, 'ThreadId': 4139, 'Module name': ModuleA , 'Message Description': My Message, 'Message' : This is the message }
```

I try splitting the log message using split on white spaces and then I can select the tokens and make the list. Something like this:

```
for i in line1.split(" "):
```

This will give tokens like this

```
['2013-Mar-05', '18:21:45.415053]', '(ThreadID)', '<Module name>', '[Logging level]',    'Message Desciption', ':', 'This is the message.']
```

And then pick and choose the tokens and put into the required list.

Is there any better way to extract the tokens in this case. There is a pattern here like `time stamp` will be in `[]` bracket , `threadId` will be inside `()`, `module name` will be inside `<>`.
Can we leverage this info and extract the token directly?

Comment: This looks like a good application for regular expressions.

Comment: In your input string `ModuleA` is not available as desired in the output. Is it this case?

Comment: Splitting this way will also split up the message, if it contains spaces.

Comment: the message will be [2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (1234) <ModuleA> [Debug]    Opening the file : c:\a.txt.

Comment: which should be converted like>>

Comment: {'time stamp': 2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053, 'ThreadId': 1234, 'Module name': ModuleA , 'Message Description': Opening the file , 'Message' : c:\a.txt }

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very similar answer to @Oli however the regex is a bit more readable and I use `groupdict()` so there's no need to form a new dictionary as it is created by the regexp. The log string is parsed left to right, consuming each match.

```
fmt = re.compile(
      r'\[(?P<timestamp>.+?)\]\s+' # Save everything within [] to group timestamp
      r'\((?P<thread_id>.+?)\)\s+' # Save everything within () to group thread_id
      r'\<(?P<module_name>.+?)\>\s+' # Save everything within <> to group module_name
      r'\[(?P<log_level>.+?)\]\s+' # Save everything within [] to group to log_level
      r'(?P<message_desc>.+?)(\s:\s|$)' # Save everything before \s:\s or end of line to           group message_desc,
      r'(?P<message>.+$)?' # if there was a \s:\s, save everything after it to group   message. This last group is optional
      )

log = '[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (4139) <ModuleA> [DEBUG]  Message Desciption : An example message!'

match = fmt.search(log)

print match.groupdict()
```

Examples:

```
log = '[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (4139) <ModuleA> [DEBUG]  Message Desciption : An       example message!'
match = fmt.search(log)

print match.groupdict() 
{'log_level': 'DEBUG',
 'message': 'An example message!',
 'module_name': 'ModuleA',
 'thread_id': '4139',
 'timestamp': '2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053'}
```

Example with your first test string from the comments of this answer

```
log = '[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (0x7aa5e3a0) <Logger> [Info] Opened settings file : /usr/local/ABC/ABC/var/loggingSettings.ini'

match = fmt.search(log)

print match.groupdict()
{'log_level': 'Info',
 'message': '/usr/local/ABC/ABC/var/loggingSettings.ini',
 'message_desc': 'Opened settings file',
 'module_name': 'Logger',
 'thread_id': '0x7aa5e3a0',
 'timestamp': '2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053'}
```

Example with your second test string from the comments of this answer:

```
log = '[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (0x7aa5e3a0) <Logger> [Info] Creating a new settings file'

match = fmt.search(log)

print match.groupdict()
{'log_level': 'Info',
 'message': None,
 'message_desc': 'Creating a new settings file',
 'module_name': 'Logger',
 'thread_id': '0x7aa5e3a0',
 'timestamp': '2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053'}
```

EDIT: Fixed to work with OP's examples.

Comment: You should use non-greedy qualifiers: `.+?`. For example, `.+\:\s+` skips everything until the _last_ colon that is followed by whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @JanneKarila, missed that one. Changed all of them although maybe only the one you mentioned was necessary. Works fine now.

Comment: @msvalkon hi i got SyntaxError: invalid syntax for In [150]: match.groupdict(). Any idea??

Comment: @dlp seems like you copied my console output. The `In [150]:` and `Out[150]:` are [iPython](http://ipython.org/) console output. Copy paste up to `print match.groupdict()` (entire first code block) and it should work fine.

Comment: @msvalkon .thanks for the prompt reply. But i got this error now>>AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'

Comment: @sunshooter show me to string you're trying to parse. If it matches your original description, it should work. `AttributeError` is raised because nothing matched and the `fmt.search(log)` return `None`

Comment: @msvalkon These are the two lines>>[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (0x7aa5e3a0) <Logger> [Info] Opened settings file : /usr/local/ABC/ABC/var/loggingSettings.ini
[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (0x7aa5e3a0) <Logger> [Info] Creating a new settings file

Comment: @msvalkon Also there may be possibility that Message Description is missing ...like in second string..but the message is there

Comment: @sunshooter Fixed to work with your examples. It was not clear to me that the `message description` should have been a group on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression, hope this helps!

```
import re

string = '[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (4444) <Module name> [Logging level]  Message Desciption : This is the message.'

regex = re.compile(r'\[(?P<timestamp>[^\]]*?)\] \((?P<threadid>[^\)]*?)\) \<(?P<modulename>[^\>]*?)\>[^:]*?\:(?P<message>.*?)$')

for match in regex.finditer(string):
    dict = {'timestamp': match.group("timestamp"), 'threadid': match.group("threadid"), 'modulename': match.group('modulename'), 'message': match.group('message')}

print dict
```

output:

`{'timestamp': '2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053', 'message': ' This is the message.', 'modulename': 'Module name', 'threadid': '4444'}`

Explanation: I'm using groups to mark parts of my regex for use in the script later. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for more info. Basically I'm going through the line from left to right, looking for the delimiters [,<,( etc.

Comment: Looks great. Could you also add some explanation to your regex?

Comment: tried this code got this error: `regex = re.compile(r'\[(?P[^\]]*?)\] \((?P[^\)]*?)\) \[^\>]*?)\>[^:]*?\:(?P.*?)$')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unknown specifier: ?P[`

Comment: sorry, the code was messed up because of the code tags..it should work now

Comment: You can skip the `regex.finditer` by doing something like: `match = regex.search(string); print match.groupdict()`

Comment: @Kivek if my answer helped you, could you select it as the answer for your question? Thanks!

Comment: @oli thanks ..It works gr8!. Alos what does ( ) metacharacter do in regex...I couldnt find info on these on the link you have given

Comment: @Oli I tried my level best to understand the regex you wrote and i am not 100 percent clear. 
It will be great if you can explain how you extract timestamp from the string , as i have to extend this regex
Ok. i know timestamp will be in [] inside this
\[(?P<timestamp>[^\]]*?)\]>>>this part extracts timestamp, so please explain how you came up with this regex

Comment: this is the format: (?P<timestamp> your regex here ). It's a named group. The regex inside is: [^]] = match every symbol except ']', and the signs after it '*?' mean: keep doing it till we reach ']'.

Comment: Thanks Oli. i have couple of questions. It looks i understood most of the part except few
1> Why are we using in the beginning  \\[ when we have used raw which will not allow escape character
2> After the group thread id , the remaining regex  looks like \<(?P<modulename>[^\>]*?)\>[^:]*?\:(?P<message>.*?)$
What's the purpose of \< in the beginning. it will be great if you explain how are you fetching the message part.
3> In this you are fetching the message that is part after :. I want the message group to contain both its description+message.

Comment: Ex:-[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (0x7aa5e3a0) <Logger> [Info] Opened settings file : /usr/local/ABC/ABC/var/loggingSettings.ini 
so the message group should contain >> Opened settings file : /usr/local/ABC/ABC/var/loggingSettings.ini>>everything after [info] is my whole message string

Comment: @Oli please advice if there is an online which can be useful here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about the following? (The comments explain what's going on)

```
log = '[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (ThreadID) <Module name> [Logging level]    Message Description : This is the message.'

# Define functions on how to proces the different kinds of tokens
time_stamp = logging_level = lambda x: x.strip('[ ]')
thread_ID = lambda x: x.strip('( )')
module_name = lambda x: x.strip('< >')
message_description = message = lambda x: x

# Names of the tokens used to make the dictionary keys
keys = ['time stamp', 'ThreadId',
        'Module name', 'Logging level',
        'Message Description', 'Message']
# Define functions on how to process the message
funcs = [time_stamp, thread_ID,
         module_name, logging_level,
         message_description, message]
# Define the tokens at which to split the message
split_on = [']', ')', '>', ']', ':']

msg_dict = {}

for i in range(len(split_on)):
    # Split up the log one token at a time
    temp, log = log.split(split_on[i], 1)
    # Process the token using the defined function
    msg_dict[keys[i]] = funcs[i](temp) 

msg_dict[keys[i]] = funcs[i](log) # Process the last token
print msg_dict
```

Comment: @ Dhara your solutions works great except one  case.. I don't have message description or message it itself. Anything after logging level is my message. so how should i rephrase message_description = message = lambda x: x function.

Comment: @sunshooter simply remove Message description from the keys and funcs lists; and, remove the last ':' to avoid splitting the text on that token.

Answer (score 0):

Although using [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in this case is simpler, in-case you don't want to use it,
Try this,

```
string = '[2013-Mar-05 18:21:45.415053] (ThreadID) <Module name> [Logging level]    Message Desciption : This is the message.'

# the main function, return the items between start and end.
def get_between(start, end, string):
    in_between = 0
    c_str = ''
    items = []
    indexes = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        char = string[i]
        if char == start:
            if in_between == 0: indexes.append(i) # if starting bracket
            in_between += 1
        elif char == end:
            in_between -= 1
            if in_between == 0: indexes.append(i) # if ending bracket
        elif in_between > 0:
            c_str += char
        if in_between == 0 and c_str != '': # after ending bracket
            items.append(c_str)
            c_str = ''
    return items, indexes

# As both Time Stamp, and Logging Level are between []s,
# And as message comes after Logging Level,
data,last_indexes = get_between('[',']',string)
time_stamp, logging = data
# We only want the first item in the first list
thread_id = get_between('(',')',string)[0][0]
module = get_between('<','>',string)[0][0]

last = max(last_indexes)
# extracting the message    
message = ''.join(string[last+1:].split(':')[1:]).strip()

mydict = {'Time':time_stamp, 'Thread ID':thread_id,'Module':module,'Logging Level':logging,'Message':message}
print mydict
```

Here, we get the characters between the 2 "classifiers" and work with them...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a consistent log format, why not use macros for indexes?

Example

```
DATE = 0
TIME = 1
TID = 2
MODULE = 3
LOG_LVL = 4
MESSAGE = 5 (or more like 7)

log = ['2013-Mar-05', '18:21:45.415053]', '(ThreadID)', '<Module name>', '[Logging level]',    'Message Desciption', ':', 'This is the message.']
```

And then just access either using log[DATE] or what not? Eventually by using " ".join on the chunks you want to stitch together before using an index based accessing. Then you can populate your dictionary however you may wish to.

It's not as neat as Oli's solution but it can do the work :)